# Twitter Boostrap grid - untraditional break behavior

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use the Bootstrap grid system to achieve the following:

-When the screen width is greater than the threshhold of the col-lg-X class, then there is 2 rows with 3 columns, but once the screen width is below col-lg-X I would like those columns to collapse into 3 rows of 2 columns.  Is this possible with the boot strap grid?

```
When greater than the break threshold of col-lg-X:

X   X   X
X   X   X

when less than col-lg-X:

X   X
X   X
X   X
```

What I'm starting with is as follows:

```
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-image">
                <img class="shadow" ng-src="{{$index == currentPage ? page.pics[0] : ''}}"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-image">
                <img class="shadow" ng-src="{{$index == currentPage ? page.pics[1] : ''}}"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-image">
                <img class="shadow" ng-src="{{$index == currentPage ? page.pics[2] : ''}}"></img>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-image">
                <img class="shadow" ng-src="{{$index == currentPage ? page.pics[3] : ''}}"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-image">
                <img class="shadow" ng-src="{{$index == currentPage ? page.pics[4] : ''}}"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-image">
                <img class="shadow" ng-src="{{$index == currentPage ? page.pics[5] : ''}}"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried to get crafty by doing something like this, but clearly the col-lg-6 will only break after its smaller than that threshold.  I

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-image">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <img class="shadow" ng-src="{{$index == currentPage ? page.pics[3] : ''}}"></img>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <img class="shadow" ng-src="{{$index == currentPage ? page.pics[3] : ''}}"></img>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-image">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <img class="shadow" ng-src="{{$index == currentPage ? page.pics[3] : ''}}"></img>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <img class="shadow" ng-src="{{$index == currentPage ? page.pics[3] : ''}}"></img>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-image">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <img class="shadow" ng-src="{{$index == currentPage ? page.pics[3] : ''}}"></img>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <img class="shadow" ng-src="{{$index == currentPage ? page.pics[3] : ''}}"></img>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Yup. What have you tried?

Comment: edits can be seen above

Comment: You want this to change to 1200px right ? Which is the lower lever of col-lg-*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'md' breakpoint.. It's the next on down from `lg`

`<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">..`

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/fl5EE6jVFQ

Comment: This is it! Thank you.  I didn't realize you could have N number of elements with col-lg-*.  I thought each row had to total 12 columns or bad things would happen.  It looks like the actual effect is that elements will fall into a row until their column exceeds 12 cols, then a new row begins.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So if I did not get your question wrong, you can specify multiple column layouts. As:

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-6 gallery-image">
 </div>
```

The bootstrap will interpret this as

```
 if (screen.width >= 1200px)
        //class is col-lg-6
 else 
     //class is col-sm-
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isnt quite the result I was looking for.  Basically, any screen width larger than when it breaks for col-sm-X I want 2 rows of 3 columns, and when it breaks for col-sm-X I want 3 rows of 2 columns.

Comment: What about the medium screens ?